# Rails ActiveRecord not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This will return the data that I want from my database when I call it in rails console:

```
class VendorFinding < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "vendor_findings"
    self.primary_key = "vendor_findings_id"

    def self.getReleventData()
        return VendorFinding
        .select([:ContactPerson, :contact_email])
        .where(Status: "Open")
    end
end
```

But when I try to INSERT/UPDATE a row it pretends everything went well but when I check the database there is no new record.
Rails Console Example:

```
irb(main):004:0> myFinding = VendorFinding.new
=> #<VendorFinding vendor_findings_id: nil, ContactPerson: nil, contact_email: nil, Status: nil>

irb(main):007:0> myFinding.ContactPerson = "Myself"                                                                     
=> "Myself"
irb(main):008:0> myFinding
=> #<VendorFinding vendor_findings_id: nil, ContactPerson: "Myself", contact_email: nil, Status: nil>
irb(main):009:0> myFinding.save
   (1.9ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (1.9ms)  INSERT INTO `vendor_findings` (`ContactPerson`) VALUES ('Myself')
   (1.8ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> true    
irb(main):012:0> VendorFinding.where("ContactPerson = 'Myself'")                                                      
  VendorFinding Load (3.2ms)  SELECT `vendor_findings`.* FROM `vendor_findings` WHERE (ContactPerson = 'Myself')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<VendorFinding vendor_findings_id: 905, ContactPerson: "Myself", contact_email: nil, Status: nil]>
```

It pretends that it updated the DB, but when I check MySQL DB, the record isn't there and the record count total is the same as before the operation. There is no validation going on on the DB side and the type of the parameters are VARCHAR(65) except the id, which is INT.

I'm newish to rails and am trying to get ActiveRecord to interact with a legacy database that is still in use, so I can't modify the column names to suit rails convention. Is there maybe something else that I need to do to get this working? Or maybe that's not the issue at all.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Update with database.yml file:

```
 development:
   adapter: mysql2
   host: <dbname>.db.<corpname>.com
   port: 8200
   database: Safety
   encoding: utf8
   collation: utf8_general_ci
   pool: 5
   <password_stuff_removed_for_stack_overflow>

   adapter: sqlite3
   database: ":memory:"

 beta:
   adapter: mysql2
   host: <dbname>.db.<corpname>.com
   port: 8200
   database: Safety
   encoding: utf8
   collation: utf8_general_ci
   pool: 5
   <password_stuff_removed_for_stack_overflow>

 production:
   adapter: mysql2
   host: <dbname>.db.<corpname>.com
   port: 8200
   database: Safety
   encoding: utf8
   collation: utf8_general_ci
   pool: 5
   <password_stuff_removed_for_stack_overflow>

 test:
   adapter: sqlite3
   database: db/test.sqlite3
```

Comment: could you update this question to include your database.yml file contents? more likely than not, rails console IS updating the database, just not the one you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this part of database.yml:

```
 development:
   adapter: mysql2
   host: <dbname>.db.<corpname>.com
   port: 8200
   database: Safety
   encoding: utf8
   collation: utf8_general_ci
   pool: 5
   <password_stuff_removed_for_stack_overflow>

   adapter: sqlite3
   database: ":memory:"
```

The first part of this code sets your development database to be the same as your production database. Then the second part of the code overrides your earlier settings and sets the database to be `database: ":memory:"` which is basically a temporary database that's deleted as soon as the connection closes.

You can fix it like so:

```
 development:
   adapter: sqlite3
   database: "db/development.sqlite"
```

This will create an empty development database using sqlite. You will be able to see these changes by accessing the sqlite database. However you will **not** see them in your production mysql database unless you run your code in production mode.

Comment: That's the issue, Thanks. I'm a little surprised that doesn't give me an error.

Comment: @TylerMitchell generally ruby lets you 'overwrite' variable and function declarations by declaring them again later in the file. so this sort of thing wouldn't give you an error in ruby, even though it would give you an error in other languages. (whether or not this feature was a good idea is a different story entirely, but you learn to live with it.)